# Page not displaying on npm start using node, react

Tags: reactjs, npm, flux

I am attempting to make a trivial page using NPM and react.

index.html file:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Flux Comment Box </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="react"></section>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

./js/app.js

```
var CommentBox = require('./components/CommentBox.react');
var React = require('react');
window.React = React;

React.render( <CommentBox />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

./components/CommentBox.react.js

```
var CommentStore = require('../stores/CommentStore');
var React = require('react');
var CommentBox = React.createClass ({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div> HI </div>
    );
  },
});

module.exports(CommentBox);
```

When I do "npm start" (my package.json should be fine, I will post it below), it says

```
2870222 bytes written to js/bundle.js (2.44 seconds)
```

but index.html is a blank page with no errors or warnings.
What's up with this?

---

For reference, here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "Basic-comment-box",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "Basic flux project",
"main": "js/app.js",

"dependencies": {
  "classnames": "^2.1.3",
  "flux": "^2.0.0",
  "keymirror": "~0.1.0",
  "object-assign": "^1.0.0",
  "react": "^0.12.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^6.2.0",
    "envify": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-cli": "^0.4.3",
    "reactify": "^0.15.2",
    "uglify-js": "~2.4.15",
    "watchify": "^2.1.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d js/app.js",
    "build": "browserify . -t [envify --NODE_ENV production] | uglifyjs -cm > js/bundle.min.js",
    "test": "jest"
},
"author": "Timothy Chu",
"license": "Apache 2",
"browserify": {
"transform": [
  "reactify",
  "envify"
]
},
"jest": {
"rootDir": "./js"
}
}
```

Comment: Problem was that I should have wrote module.exports = ....., instead of module.exports(...). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.**for render** you should use **ReactDOM** insted of React

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render( <CommentBox />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

2.**reactify is DEPRECATED:** Use ***[babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify)*** instead (make sure you configured Babel with babel-preset-react).